# Timezone in Calendar

Tags: calendar

I am planning an international flight. I have the flight details, with local departure times and arrival time at destination. I have entered these into my Calendar.

Due to the differences in timezone this appears as an 8 hour trip, when in reality is is 19.

Is there a way to enter timezone so the duration shows correctly and so when I adjust my timezone on arrival, it will show the correct local time.

I have turned on timezone support, but there seems to be no way to have a different timezone for start/end times.

Comment: your duration is the start and the end of the event (in local time). When you arrive in new time zone it will change to that local time, but your duration you entered will remain the same.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The airline gives arrival in destination local time, so I have to do my own conversion back to my time zone to enter event. I can do this, but particularly when a DST change is due during the trip I usually get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be possible, so I made a second entry "arrival" for the destination timezone, then drag the finish time of the first to match.